# Which approach is better - change tracking attribute in each table vs one tracker table

Tags: database-design

I am trying to decide between 2 approaches to tracking whether a record has changed or not and when and by whom. I am not interested in obtaining the actual data that has changed but only the fact that the data has changed. I am using SQL Server 2008.

First approach is to have the following 6 columns in each tables: Created On, Created By, Last Updated On, Last Updated by, Deleted On and Deleted By.

Second approach is to have a single table, let us call it Change Tracker,  which has those 6 columns and other tables would have a FK to the Change Tracker table.

which is a better practice and why?

Also, do I need to have these columns if I enable change tracking in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see no advantages of second approach, always using first one. 
btw, deleted_by and deleted_on are redundant fields. created_xx and updated_xx fields are enough

Comment: thanks for the quick comment. Why do you say that deleted_xx are redundant? we want to track the deleted records.

Comment: you're going to use deleted_xx fields to determine that the record is deleted? imho, the best and most nice way is to add to record some activity attribute of boolean datatype(e.g. the field named ACTIVE). so in order to 'delete' record we must update the value of ACTIVE field and update_date, updated_by in single UPDATE query. In order to select all active records we just have to make query like "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ACTIVE=1". I know that Oracle Applications use such approach, and I agree with them))

Comment: I see the point and thanks for elaborating. How do I set the primary key in this case - if I had a deleted_on, I can combine my natural key plus deleted_on as a primary key. In this case, I can't combine it with isActive since it would then allow only one deleted record. I thought about having an isActive column but had this question